# Use bootstrap dropdown list to submit form

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have the simplest dropdown list which sends form to server dependend on choosen option:

```
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <form name="add" method="post">
            <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name=provider>
                <option value=first>first</option>
                <option value=second>second</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I want to use [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#single-button-dropdowns) for that, however have no idea at all how I could achieve the same functionality. Any ideas?

Full html with bootstrap:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown button
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to keep the request logic and send a standard POST request you can have a `<form>` with only one input of type hidden and update its value dynamically. The value can be stored and extracted from a data attribute of the `<a>` link, here is a simple implementation:

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="first" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="second" href="#">Another action</a>
    </div>
    <form class="d-none" name="add" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="provider" value=""> 
    </form>
</div>
```

And some simple jQuery code:

```js
$('.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item').on('click', function() {
  var element = $(this);
  var form = $('form', element.closest('.dropdown'));
  
  $('input[name="provider"]', form).val(element.data('value'))
  
  form.submit();
});
```